# HDMI to DisplayPort monitor?

Tags: hdmi, dvi, displayport

I got a monitor with DVI-D and DisplayPort, and I have a a notebook and a graphics card I want to connect to it. The graphics card has DVI-D output, so that's the simple part. But the notebook has HDMI only. How do you connect HDMI to DisplayPort? I only found adapters for the other way round, which are also fairly expensive (i.e. DP->HDMI.) Or should I get a HDMI to DVI and then a DVI-Y-cable to connect everything via DVI?

Comment: When you say "(...) and a graphics card" do you mean an external Video Card or a PC that is already connected to that monitor?

Comment: Separate PC with graphics card

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An [HDMI to DVI adapter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812186019&cm_re=hdmi_to_dvi-_-12-186-019-_-Product) would be more natural as the two connections carry the same video signals.  Don't try to save $2 and get the wrong one.  The one I linked to will work for all current HDMI to DVI connections.

**UPDATE**

DVI and HDMI carry the same signal, DisplayPort and HDMI do not.  Every DVI connection can be passively converted (i.e. using an adapter, not a converter) to HDMI.  DisplayPort can only be passively converted (i.e. using an [adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Compatibility_with_HDMI.2C_DVI_and_VGA)) to HDMI if the DisplayPort in question is designed for "[dual mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Compatibility_with_HDMI.2C_DVI_and_VGA)", otherwise an [active converter box](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815158264) will be needed.

Comment: Similarly, an HDMI to DVI cable (HDMI on one end, DVI on the other) would also do the trick.

Comment: Yup, basically a long adapter :)

Comment: Would be nice if the original question would be answered. I want to switch multiple components into my 30" monitor, using DisplayPort. I'm having trouble finding a way to connect an HDMI device to one of the DisplayPort connections on the switch. I'd prefer to use the one switch and not have to ALSO switch inputs on my monitor.

Comment: @MarkRenouf The original question was answered, but I have provided some more information on why DVI to HDMI is preferred (if it is an option) over DisplayPort to HDMI.  DisplayPorts with dual mode are more common these days than they were 2 years ago when I answered this question, so converting DisplayPort to HDMI is now more trivial (and cheaper) than it once was.

Comment: Yes, converting from DisplayPort to HDMI would seem to be quite trivial these days looking at the plethora of cheap adapters and cables available on Amazon and eBay. However, these appear to be one way. The OP is initially asking about HDMI to DP (which is the problem I also have). For HDMI to DP I have found no cheap adapters, only very expensive "active" converters (60 GBP / 90 USD plus). HDMI to DVI would still seem to be the far more practical solution. (In hindsight I wish I'd bought a monitor with an HDMI input and known about this HDMI/DP incompatibility!)